# Keeping a custom div on top of the layout while allowing the users to surf through websites

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, iframe

```css
#ontop {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 90%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
#content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    top: 10%;
    bottom: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

Given the above CSS, is it possible to load an external website within the `#content` DOM element to allow the users to surf through it? The `#ontop` element would then be able to propose some additional features to the currently loaded website.

---

An `iframe` typically behaves like I want:

```html
<div id="ontop">Always on top</div>
<iframe id="content" src="http://en.wikipedia.org/"></iframe>
```

Some websites (such as Stack Overflow) avoid accessing their content within an `iframe` for security purposes though.

```html
<div id="ontop">Always on top</div>
<iframe id="content" src="http://www.stackoverflow.com/"></iframe>
```

The above snippet won't load the website content, while throwing the following error: *refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options*.

---

I tried then to suit my needs with AJAX (see [this mod](https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax/) to allow cross-domain AJAX requests with jQuery):

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(data) {
                $("#content").html(data.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="ontop">Always on top</div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

This works *almost*, since two problems occur:

1. the rendering fails for complex websites (such as Stack Overflow);
2. the users can't surf through the loaded website since the URLs (e.g. links, requests) are now relative to the server running the above script.

---

I finally tried to combine the two first solutions:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(data) {
                $("#content").contents().find('body').append(data.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="ontop">Always on top</div>
<iframe id="content"></iframe>
```

This is a little bit better:

1. the rendering fails *less* (for example, Google still mess it up while Stack Overflow not anymore);
2. the URLs are still wrong.

---

How could achieve my goal? Either a solution to manage these relative URLs, or a totally different one that still suits my needs, would both be welcomed.

---

Since jsFiddle isn't powerful enough for such complex asynchronous requests, below are the source codes of the three attempts I provided:

- Using `iframe`: [iframe.html](http://pastebin.com/tGpw0ncM)
- Using AJAX: [ajax.html](http://pastebin.com/BufJmacM)
- Using both: [both.html](http://pastebin.com/E3sj1A2f)

Comment: long time i haven't seen a nicely elaborated question/situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you've already discovered why this is difficult to do on the web, partially deliberately in order to prevent people from maliciously loading their website into another website.

With that in mind, if I were in your position I would investigate writing either a browser extension ([Chrome](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html), [Firefox](http://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2009/01/28/how-to-develop-a-firefox-extension/)) ,or perhaps a [bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet), all of which preserve the site's functionality while at the same time injecting JavaScript into the page that gets around the permissions issues that you are experiencing.

The advantage of a bookmarklet is that it should be the least amount of work and the most cross-browser solution, at the cost of power and flexibility.  If you'd like the ability to have nice interfaces that act like part of the browser and don't require the user to activate the bookmarklet whenever it's appropriate, then look into an extension, especially if your target audience is Chrome/FF users.

Note that if you absolutely have to have IE users, developing extensions for IE is not very user friendly, although certainly doable.

Also, if you want to prototype your FF extension a bit before committing to developing one, look into [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/), an extension that essentially lets you write a lightweight version of extension code without worrying about the associated packaging.